# After installing printer windows 7 will fail to boot if printer is not turned on

Tags: windows-7, boot, printer

I just installed an HP Deskjet 460 onto my Windows 7 x64 system. It installed using the default drivers windows found. My problem is that after installing the printer if it is either unplugged or turned off when windows boots I get the error "a required device is missing or inaccessible". I uninstalled the printer but still get this error. The printer is connected via USB to the computer, it can be plugged into any USB port to allow windows to boot.

Comment: Keep in mind when you uninstall a printer the relate driver won't be removed until you explicitly request so. Can you boot into Safe Mode when the printer is either unplugged/turned off?

Comment: Nope, the error appears before I could even get the option for boot mode to appear

Comment: Connect the printer and reinstall the driver again. Then remove the printer *and* the driver by following the steps listed in this article: http://www.solveyourtech.com/remove-old-printer-drivers/ Restart when done.

Comment: @and31415 unfortunately even after removing the entire Driver Package the problem still exists.

Comment: Have you got any restore points dating before the issue occurred?

Comment: I do, but how will that affect programs I have installed/uninstalled since then and new documents on the c:?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that this printer had a card reader which was listed as a storage device in windows. I had to remove the printer and go into Computer Management to delete the drives assigned to the card reader. Once that was done I could boot fine.